# Is there a photogrammetry addon or setup that works similar to FaceBuilder addon for NUKE?

Tags: photogrammetry

Is there an arrangement that allows similar pinning of a generic (initially)  mirrored mesh/facemesh ?

[KeenTools FaceBuilder Demo 2018](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vPAktlmMU6E)

I'm fairly sure Blender can come close to this with existing tools.

Comment: That's quite an advanced feature. I'm not aware of anything comparable as  an add-on for Blender.

Comment: Seems like a deformation setup that could be arranged even with existing tools.  Though I also figured it was strange, a feature like fSpy isn't integrated into Blender (motion tracking) by default.  Also, Edge detection would complement the system greatly.

Comment: You need quite a bit more. First you need a parametric model of a human head, then you need advanced tools for snapping and pose estimation. Automated texture projection and tracking would also need to be implemented based on Blender's features. I'm not saying can't be done, but that would require a lot of work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is now !

The [addon by KeenTools](https://keentools.io/download/facebuilder-for-blender)

Here's a [tutorial by CGMatter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sf88UeC7LmE&t=4s)